# JSR 330 and Guice interoperability

Tags: java, dependency-injection, glassfish, guice, jsr330

Does anybody have experience with JSR 330 vs Guice?  From what I gather Guice is not an implementation of JSR 330 but if it is anything like Hibernate and JPA the implementation supports a bunch of additional functionality no in the API.  Since I am already using GWT-Dispatch, Warp-persist guice-serlvet, etc would there be anything gained by moving to an EJB container supporting JSR 330?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the official announcement mail, [FYI: JSR-330 support now in Guice SVN](http://markmail.org/message/djvzffz6acytlbmt):

> I've implemented support for JSR-330
>   to Guice. This JSR standardizes
>   annotations like @Inject and the
>   Provider interfaces for Java
>   platforms. It doesn't yet specify how
>   applications are configured, so it has
>   no analog to Guice's modules.
>
> This new feature may cause pain for
>   IDE users. Since there's now two
>   @Inject annotations, IntelliJ etc.
>   will prompt you when it needs an
>   import. Either one will work, but the
>   new dialogs will be quite annoying!
>   Even worse, the two @Named annotations
>   aren't (yet) equivalent. So if you
>   apply the wrong annotation, you'll get
>   a configuration error. I'm thinking
>   about ways to address this.
>
> This work is ongoing. I recommend
>   continuing to use the old
>   com.google.inject annotations until
>   the dust settles.
>   http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JSR330

This mail has been sent September 7, 2009. It's up to you to decide if the dust has settled but I'd wait a bit more and stick with the guice annotations as recommended.

Comment: This is still in SVN - is there a prognosis for when a release containing this will happen?

Comment: @Thorbjørn I don't know and I don't see much interest for JSR-330 from Guice (http://markmail.org/thread/pysiphf5t6txuh5p). This doesn't really surprise me: what Bob Lee and Rob Johnson did with this spec was pure obstruction (very close to sabotage) and I consider JSR-330 as a poor, botched, political spec. Very sad.

Comment: Agreed.   I was hoping for convergence of guice and seam to get the same independence as for servlet containers, but apparently this will not happen.  I added Weld to our primary stand-alone application today, and the naive implementation added 10 seconds to the start up time.... Sigh.

Comment: Guice 3.0 is in late beta.  Works well for us.

Answer (score 7):

Guice 2.0 does not support JSR 330, but Guice SVN includes a [JSR 330-compatible injector](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JSR330).